# Blank screen on install

Tags: install

I have everything loaded, my path to "craft" is correct and the database credentials are correct but when I go to domain.com/admin, it pulls up a blank screen. Not a 404, server error, of the "oops" screen. It's just blank.

My folder permissions are also correct. Anyone else had this? I checked the server requirements and those are also within the correct parameters.

Jeremy

Comment: Did you rename `htaccess` to `.htaccess`? What happens if you go to `domain.com/index.php?p=admin`?

Comment: Are you positive there are no syntax errors in your `general.php` and `db.php`? (happened to me: missing `,`). Run them through [http://phpcodechecker.com/](http://phpcodechecker.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I simply deleted everything and re-uploaded and it worked. It must have been a corrupt upload because I'm up and running now. Thanks!